# Kafka 0.9 consumer stop consuming messages from the partitions it was originally assigned after rebalancing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, bigdata

I'm writing a Kafka Consumer Client with 0.9 Java API.

I've created a topic with 15 partitions (0-14). Started three consumer clients, and then start the producer to produce 50,000 messages.

After these three consumer clients started to process, i stopped one of them. After a while, rebalancing happened, and the problem occurred.

Problem is that, when i started three consumer clients, they all got assigned to partitions. for example:

```
client 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

client 2: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

client 3: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

After i stopped client 3, rebalancing happened.The new assignment is:

```
client 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

client 2: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

But after rebalancing, client 1 won't consuming messages from 0-5 & client 2 won't consuming from 9.

My consumer configuration is as below :

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 8192);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
```